# Azure Blob Storage not Uploading

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage

I'm trying to upload a text file from a stream to AzureBlobStorage in .Net Core but it seems to be failing silently. I am reading data from a database and writing it into a `MemoryStream` using a `StreamWriter`. At the point I am uploading to BlobStorage, the `Stream` has a Length of 7147 so I know it's got data in it.

Here's my code to upload the file:

```cs
public static async void UploadFromStream(string fileName, Stream stream, string fileExtenstion = "txt")
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionString);
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("logs");
    // By this point, I have a reference to my `logs` container which exists
    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{fileName}.{fileExtenstion}");

    try
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Called by:

```cs
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        writer.WriteLine(
            $"[{reader["Timestamp"]}][{reader["Level"].ToString().ToUpper()}] :: {reader["Message"]}{(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reader["Exception"].ToString()) ? " -- " + reader["Exception"] : "")}");
    }
    Task.Run(() => StorageService.UploadFromStream($"logfile_{DateTime.Today:s}", memoryStream)).Wait();
}
```

I don't get inside my Catch block so I don't think I'm hitting any Exceptions, but when I check my Storage, there's nothing there. The application runs through with no errors.

I have even tried using `byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray()` and using the `blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync` but still to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** use `async void` (except for Event handlers). See [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Use `public static async Task UploadFromStream` instead.

You will probably get an exception and be able to track down the error.

Comment: I just read your comment and that change then meant I was seeing an exception!! I had a rogue typo in my connection string, but I wasn't seeing the error. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why `Task.Run(() => StorageService.UploadFromStream($"logfile_{DateTime.Today:s}", memoryStream)).Wait();` and why can't you just `await` on it like below provided you change the method signature to `public static async Task UploadFromStream(...` as already suggested in another answer

```
await StorageService.UploadFromStream($"logfile_{DateTime.Today:s}", memoryStream)
```

Comment: Because I'm running the task from a synchronous context (Main method in a Console app)

Comment: @MattBrewerton - if you can set your project to use a later version of C# you *can* have async main (at the bottom of this post of mine is where to set it, if you're not already aware https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/calling-asp-net-web-api-end-points-for-testing-purposes-with-refit) which may be useful to know

Comment: @Rob Thanks for that, I changed Rider to use C#7 and looks like it works as expected with async Main!

Comment: @Rob you might want to post that as answer